# Does processing the data of a document snapshot obtained from Firebase count as a read?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, billing

This question is regarding the billing of Firebase.

Does processing the data of a document snapshot obtained from Firebase count as a read?

So does the below code incur costs on my Billing plan and thus counts as a read or is it just post-processing the already obtained data or snapshot?

```
docSnapshot.data().toString().contains('hello')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question: So does the below code incur costs on my Billing plan and thus counts
> as a read or is it just post-processing the already obtained data or
> snapshot?

Answer: It is "just post-processing the already obtained data or snapshot". You pay one read when you fetch the document from Firestore to your client.